# Stream executing log to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, ios7, afnetworking

I am building an app for Jenkins CI and need to display a log like this: https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/job/infra_backend_pull_request_greeter/lastBuild/consoleText in the app. That is simple, the trouble comes when the CI server is actually executing the job and the lines are coming, the web browser is displaying the partial data as they come but how do I do that on the iPhone without having to reload the entire thing ... there has to be some streaming or something?

For the API I am using AFNetworking so would be great if you'd knew how to do that using that but any solution will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the `outputStream` on an `AFHTTPRequestOperation`?  There's a brief example in the wiki if you search for "Streaming": https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Introduction-to-AFNetworking

Comment: I did now but can't get it to work :(

Comment: anyone has any ideas?